# How to remove a value from localStorage after reboot?

Tags: javascript, jquery

1) Enter text in the search
2) it is saved in `localStorage`
3) press "search", and the page is reloaded,
4) the text entered there in the search bar.
It is working correctly.
But if I start to click on other pages of the website, the search bar is still populated with a value from `localStorage`.
How can it be removed at the next reboot?
What should I use (not `localStorage`)?

Comment: How us your code please

Comment: you can use the id session to vinculate it, and when reebot sure generate another id session

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You've said *"But if I start to click on other pages of the website, the search bar is still populated with a value from  localStorage."* and *"How can it be removed at the next reboot?"* but clearing it at next reboot won't help with the search bar being populated with the value on other pages (until the reboot, which could be hours, days, or even weeks later). What is your actual requirement for when this data should expire?

Comment: @Justinas I know how to remove, I don't know how to remove after a reboot

Comment: @T.J.Crowder 1) enter data 2) press "Enter", reload page 3) data entered in the searc bar 4) the next reloading of the data should be deleted

Comment: *"What should I use (not localStorage)?"* - I wouldn't use localStorage for this. If a search is reloading the whole page, can't you pre-populate the search bar in your server-side code, or include the search term in the search response and populate the search bar from there? Alternatively, *don't* reload the whole page, use Ajax to just populate the search results part without reloading everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comment you've clarified you want to do:

> 1. enter data
> 2. press "Enter"
> 3. reload page
> 4. data entered in the search bar
> 5. the next reloading of the data should be deleted

It sounds to me, then, like you don't want to use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` at all. Instead, when sending the data to the server at #2 above (I'm assuming that's what pressing Enter does), return the search bar data when the page reloads at #3 above; use that to populate the search bar. Subsequent refreshes of the page won't have that data (because you won't have sent it, so you won't have echoed it back).

A less reliable solution would be to save the data in web storage (either `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`) at #2 above, then on page load see if the data is there, use it if so, **and delete it**. Then it won't be there on subsequent page loads. I say that's less reliable because if for some reason your page doesn't reload at #3, or while the data is being sent the user opens another page on your site with this search bar thing, they could see search data. That's why including it in the response to the search makes sense.